# Passing a var as a method parameter in C#

Tags: c#, oop, var

I'm trying to pass a `var` parameter to a method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
        var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        PrintResponseStuff(response);
    }

    public static void PrintResponseStuff(var response)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
        Console.WriteLine(response.IsSuccessful);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        Console.WriteLine(response.ContentType);
    }
}
```

The easiest way would be to pass a var; however, if there's a data type that can hold `request` that should work too. Is there anyway to do this or do I need to pass each item individually?

Comment: I don't think you can? It's not a dynamic type, it's inferred and then replaced at compile time. I might be wrong though, hopefully someone else can chime in on this one.

Comment: you cannot say 'var' in a function declaration. var is just syntax short hand saying 'compiler, please type the correct type for me', its not dynamic at all.

Comment: if this method is only for writing request data then you can probably just change the `var` to `RestRequest` or whatever type request is

Comment: That keyword is not doing what you think it's doing. `var` is just shorthand for inferring the type of a variable. It is not some sort of dynamic type (that exists - but is different). Just explicitly declare the type of the parameter.

Comment: Use dynamic as datatype for response and then typecast to a http request object.

Comment: The proper way to do this is to implement an interface or abstract class which has the data and methods you need, then pass that into the function.

Comment: Why does `PrintResponseStuff()` need to accept different parameters?  You have not shown what different types you want to pass to it

Comment: @Bose_geek overkill, looking at the code in PrintResponseStuff its expecting to receive a HttpRequest object

Comment: Ok so if you are using `client.Execute()` that [always returns](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/641f428772bb176e0b2ef9ee1b2fea6ab2a02eae/RestSharp/IRestClient.cs) a `IRestResponse` so why not just make your method parameter `IRestResponse`?  Even if you use the generic overload (Execute<T>) you _already know_ the type so just make your method generic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var` is not a "type" but just compiler sugar. It is smart enough to know what type it is. In fact, you can just hover over it and see it.

Change the `PrintResponseStuff` parameter to that type.

Comment: For the record, the correct data type to assign the variable is `IRestResponse`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using RestSharp, and based on your sample code you are calling `RestClient.Execute()`, which can *only* return an [`IRestResponse`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/aadc797e09f45a857f42162a574ca3fab271e40a/RestSharp/IRestResponse.cs).  So your code can easily be:

```
static void Main()
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
    var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);

    //response is always IRestResponse if you call Execute()
    var response = client.Execute(request);

    PrintResponseStuff(response);
}

public static void PrintResponseStuff(IRestResponse response)
{
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
    Console.WriteLine(response.IsSuccessful);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    Console.WriteLine(response.ContentType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object` or `dynamic`, `var` is not possible